# SQL CASE in a WHERE with logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

I'm getting an error Incorrect syntax near '>'
Each of the fields hold decimal values, with a NOT NULL and default value of zero.
I've tried different parenthesis and I believe I'm just missing the formatting of the CASE's statement somewhere.

```
AND CASE WHEN QtyIssued <> 0 OR WM.QtyToMake <> 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd <> 0 THEN QtyIssued/WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd >= .68 ELSE 0 END
```

I need to check for zero in each of the values so I don't get divide by zero

The entire SQL is listed below:

```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING([SalesOrder], PATINDEX('%[^0]%', [SalesOrder]+'|'),                               LEN([SalesOrder])) AS SO, WM.SalesOrderLine AS SOLine, 
        SUBSTRING(WM.Job, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', WM.Job+'|'), LEN(WM.Job)) AS Job, WMat.StockCode, --WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd AS Qty2IssuedValue, 
        CEILING(WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd) AS Qty2Issue, 
                        CEILING(WMat.QtyIssued) AS QtyIssued, WMP.WipRelease, WM.JobTenderDate, 
                        WM.Complete , 
                        CASE WHEN QtyIssued = 0 OR WM.QtyToMake = 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd = 0 
                        THEN 0 ELSE (QtyIssued/(WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd)) END AS QtyNotAllocated
FROM            dbo.WipMaster AS WM INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[WipMaster+] AS WMP ON WM.Job = WMP.Job FULL OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.WipJobAllMat AS WMat ON WM.Job = WMat.Job
WHERE        (WMP.WipRelease BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND 
                                    CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-29 00:00:00', 102)) 
                                    AND CASE WHEN QtyIssued <> 0 OR WM.QtyToMake <> 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd <> 0 THEN QtyIssued/WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd >= .68 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `case` in the `where` is:

```
(CASE WHEN QtyIssued <> 0 OR WM.QtyToMake <> 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd <> 0
      THEN QtyIssued/WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd >= .68
      ELSE 0
 END)
```

This is not a boolean expression.  I'm not even sure what you intend.  Perhaps:

```
((QtyIssued <> 0 OR WM.QtyToMake <> 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd <> 0) AND
 QtyIssued/NULLIF(WM.QtyToMake, 0) * WMat.UnitQtyReqd >= .68
)
```

The `NULLIF()` prevents divide by zero.

Comment: What I was going for was to have my cake and eat it too. LOL

Comment: I wanted to see the ones with zero values in the columns, but not have the issue with divide by zero. So, here is what I came up with...   Sorry, new to forum and working out how to use it....

Comment: AND ((QtyIssued <> 0 OR WM.QtyToMake <> 0 OR WMat.UnitQtyReqd <> 0) AND
         QtyIssued/NULLIF(WM.QtyToMake, 0) * WMat.UnitQtyReqd >= .68 OR 
         QtyIssued = 0 OR WM.QtyToMake * WMat.UnitQtyReqd = 0